# How to illustrate the Simpson/Trapezoidal rules in python?

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to make a plot to illustrate the Simpson/Trapezoidal integration formula for a simple function (y=x^2). The simps and trapz functions from scipy are helpful to calculate the area but I would also like to overplot the trapeziums/parabolas on the original curve. I was wondering if there is any existing routine for this, if not, it will be helpful to get some ideas on how to make these plots.

```
   import numpy as np
   from scipy.integrate import simps, trapz

   x=np.arange(9)
   y=x**2

   area=simps(y,x)
   print area

   area=trapz(y,x)
   print area

   plot(y,x)
```

Comment: There are no standard routines for plotting what you want.  Try making the plots yourself, and if you have trouble, maybe someone here will help.  As it is, you just saying "I have this idea, write the code for me to do it."

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest matplotlib, with functions like `fill_between`,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps, trapz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

#Continous curve
x=np.arange(0,9,0.01)
y=f(x)
ax.plot(y,x, 'k-')

#Trapizium
xstep = np.arange(0,10,3)
area=trapz(y,x)
print area
ax.fill_between(f(xstep), 0, xstep)

#Simpsons
area=simps(y,x)
print area
#etc etc

plt.show()
```

Where I've only done the trap approximation, you'd need to define a function to plot the simpsons rule approximation for fill between